# gpgkey backup of privatekeys importing

Tags: windows, gnupg

I certainly had a crash of my windows, when I had to retrieve the pgp-keys I stored, I did not figure out to backup those publickeys too.
Furthermore the biggest problem seems to be, that there is a 'new' format of the stored .key-files.
It looks like this:

```
Created: 20231003T200038
Key: (protected-private-key (elg (p #
xyz
#)
```

I searched several times through the web, to figure out what format i can 'reassemble' the .key file to, so I could import them back to kleopatra, without win.